# PowerShell Get-ChildItem -Exclude and -Include not working

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

Can someone tell me what is going on here?
I can get -Filter *.log to work no problem.

```
PS C:\logs> Get-ChildItem -Filter *.log -Recurse


    Directory: C:\logs


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---         7/19/2016   2:45 PM          0 Moninitor-error-1.log
-a---         7/19/2016   2:45 PM          0 Moninitor-out-1.log
-a---         7/19/2016   2:45 PM          0 Watcher-error-3.log
-a---         7/19/2016   2:52 PM     264810 Watcher-out-3.log
-a---         7/19/2016   2:48 PM          0 FolderWatcher-error-2.log
-a---         7/19/2016   2:52 PM    7768537 FolderWatcher-out-2.log
-a---         7/19/2016   4:34 PM          0 nothing-error.log
-a---         7/19/2016   4:34 PM          0 nothing.log
-a---         7/18/2016   2:38 PM          0 log-error-0.log
-a---         7/19/2016   2:45 PM          0 log-out-0.log
```

as soon as I try to use -Include or -Exclude I get an access error.

```
PS C:\logs> Get-ChildItem -Exclude *.log -Recurse
Get-ChildItem : Access is denied
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem -Exclude *.log -Recurse
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

PS C:\logs> Get-ChildItem -Include *.log -Recurse
Get-ChildItem : Access is denied
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem -Include *.log -Recurse
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\...tor-error-1.log:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Get-ChildItem : Access is denied
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem -Include *.log -Recurse
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

What I am wanting to do is loop through the files in this directory and delete any that are older than 0 days, and don't contain error in the file name.

My current script is this.

```
#----- define parameters -----#
#----- get current date ----#
$Now = Get-Date
#----- define amount of days ----#
$Days = "0"
#----- define folder where files are located ----#
$TargetFolder = "C:\logs"
#----- define extension ----#
$Extension = "*.log"
$Skip = "*error*"
#----- define LastWriteTime parameter based on $Days ---#
$LastWrite = $Now.AddDays(-$Days)
#----- get files based on lastwrite filter and specified folder ---#
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $TargetFolder -Filter $Extension -Exclude $Skip -Recurse | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -le "$LastWrite"}
foreach ($File in $Files) 
    {
    if ($File -ne $NULL)
        {
        write-host "Deleting File $File" -ForegroundColor "DarkRed"
        Remove-Item $File.FullName | out-null
        }
    else
        {
        Write-Host "No more files to delete!" -foregroundcolor "Green"
        }
    }
```

But Anytime I sue Exclude or Include It gives me these Access Errors.

-Recurse on its own works perfectly as well...

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\.pm2\logs> Get-ChildItem -Recurse


    Directory: C:\logs


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---         7/19/2016   2:45 PM          0 Moninitor-error-1.log
-a---         7/19/2016   2:45 PM          0 Moninitor-out-1.log
-a---         7/19/2016   2:45 PM          0 Watcher-error-3.log
-a---         7/19/2016   2:52 PM     264810 Watcher-out-3.log
-a---         7/19/2016   2:48 PM          0 FolderWatcher-error-2.log
-a---         7/19/2016   2:52 PM    7768537 FolderWatcher-out-2.log
-a---         7/19/2016   4:34 PM          0 nothing-error.log
-a---         7/19/2016   4:34 PM          0 nothing.log
-a---         7/18/2016   2:38 PM          0 log-error-0.log
-a---         7/19/2016   2:45 PM          0 log-out-0.log
```

Comment: Have you tried `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` on its own? It looks like `-Filter` is applied by the file system so could be filtering out files you don't have access to before you ask for them.

Comment: yes.  -Recurse works great on its own as well.  Will edit above

Answer (score 0):

Try luck with this

```
$Extension = "*log"
    $TargetFolder = "c:\logs"
    Get-Childitem $TargetFolder -Include $Extension -Recurse 

$Extension = "*txt"
    $TargetFolder = "c:\logs"
    Get-Childitem $TargetFolder -exclude $Extension -Recurse
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, you want to use `-Filter`, because as @Guvante pointed out, it is applied by the File System Provider, and will speed things up considerably. After that just pipe to a `Where` statement to remove things with error in the name, and are not old enough.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.log -Recurse | Where{$_.name -notlike "*error*" -and $_.lastwritetime -lt [datetime]::Today}
```

Or swap out `lastwritetime` for `creationtime` if you want when the file was created instead of last modified.